# Separating vowels from a string of string data type and storing it in a new string

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    string a,v;
    cin>>a;
    while(a[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(a[i]=='a' || a[i]=='e' || a[i]=='i' || a[i]=='o' || a[i]=='u' )
        {
            v[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout<<v;
    return 0;
}
```

when i try to print v , nothing gets printed and i don't know why ! 
But, when i try to print v using while loop traversing through each character, the correct output gets printed. I want to know why ??

Comment: This program has undefined behavior. When you loop you're assigning into `v` (using `v[j]`), but `v` is empty, only `a` has contents (from `cin >> a;`)

Comment: Undefined behavior. Accessing the out-of-bounds elements of `std::string`.

Comment: but, if there was any problem in assigning , how does the correct output gets printed if i use `int i=0; while (v[i]!='\0') { cout<<v[i]; i++; }` @Borgleader

Comment: can u please elaborate ?? @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: Undefined behaviour means anything can happen, including printing out what you expected. Having it behave like you want once is not indication it's fine

Comment: @FakruBOSS What do you need me to elaborate on? As I, and many others already mentioned - it's undefined behavior - anything can happen.

Answer (score 1):

Use .at() instead of [], it does boundry checking and would have probably detected this error for you.

Your problem is that you have a string 'v' of undetermined space and you are appending to an arbitrary index of 'v'.

The solutions would be either replacing the code that append to v to:

```
    v += a.at(i);
```

And with this you've also removed a bit of complexity in the form of that second itterator j.

OR

You can reserve space in v so that the [index] operation works. So at the beginning you can do:

```
    cin>>a;
    v.reserve(a.size())
```